# Set checkBox in CustomAdapter Visible by clicking on ListView Element in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, checkbox

is it possible to call a method in my `CustomAdapter` to set a checkbox Visible/Gone by clicking on an Element on my Fragments Listview? Ive got those two methods:

```
    public void setCheckBoxSelectItemVisible(){
    checkBoxSelectItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return;
}

public void setCheckBoxSelectItemGone(){
    checkBoxSelectItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return;
}
```

But How do I access them from my Fragment? Or do I have do chose another way?

(I want to set the checkbox visible by after "long click" on one of the ListView Elements)
Fragment:

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {

    [...]

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

        getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.listView));

        registerForContextMenu(view);

        final Context context = getContext();
        mydb = new DbHelper(context);
        locationpicker = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_locations);
        roomnr = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_roomNr);

        Drawable drawableForFabAdd = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabmain.setImageDrawable(drawableForFabAdd);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabmain.animate().translationY(0);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabmain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).scanQRCode();
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).loadListViewFragment();
            }
        });

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabdelete.animate().translationY(0);

        final String locationNamesFromTableArray = mydb.getLocationNames();

        if(!locationNamesFromTableArray.isEmpty()){
            String[] roomNumbersFromTableArrayFinal = locationNamesFromTableArray.split("\t");
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_locations;
            adapter_locations = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, roomNumbersFromTableArrayFinal);
            locationpicker.setAdapter(adapter_locations);

            setFabdeleteVisible(listViewOk);
        }

        locationpicker.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                actualLocation = locationpicker.getSelectedItem().toString();
                locationOk = true;
                setFabsVisible(roomNrOk, true, listViewOk);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        roomnr.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{3}$");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

                roomNrOk = m.find();
                setFabsVisible(roomNrOk, locationOk, listViewOk);
            }
        });

        dataList = mydb.getElementsWithoutRoom();


        if (!dataList.isEmpty()) {
            final String[] dataListArray = dataList.split("\n");
            Log.d("DATALIST", dataListArray[0]);

            final ListAdapter dataListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, dataListArray);
            final ListView dataListListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_datalist);

            dataListListView.setAdapter(dataListAdapter);



            dataListListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
                    if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabmain.animate().translationY(300);
                    }
                    if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabmain.animate().translationY(0);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                }
            });

            listViewOk = true;
            setFabsVisible(roomNrOk, locationOk, true);
            setFabdeleteVisible(listViewOk);


            dataListListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    selectedFromList = (dataListListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                    selectedElementArray = selectedFromList.split("\t");
                    dataListListView.showContextMenu();
                }

            });

            dataListListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    (CustomListAdapter).setCheckBoxSelectItemVisible();

                    return true;
                }
            });


        [...]

        return view;
    }

    public void reloadListViewFragment(){
        Fragment fragment;
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragment = new ListViewFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

   [...]   
}
```

CustomAdapter:

```
class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    String doubleTab = "\t\t";
    CheckBox checkBoxSelectItem;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, String[] dataListFinal) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_datalist ,dataListFinal);
    }
    public String allElementsAdapter = "";

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater iteminflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = iteminflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_datalist, parent, false);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.list_icon_product);
        TextView textViewlabel = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_datalist_label_textview);
        TextView textViewdetails1 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_datalist_textview_details_1);
        TextView textViewdetails2 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_datalist_textview_details_2);
        checkBoxSelectItem = (CheckBox) customView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_Item);

        String singleListItem = getItem(position);
        String[] singleListItemArray = singleListItem.split("\t");
        String id = singleListItemArray[0];
        String product = singleListItemArray[1];



        allElementsAdapter = product + label + serial + mac + daaid + bill;

        switch (product) {
            case "Pc":
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_pc_circle);
                break;
            case "Laptop":
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_laptop_circle);
                break;
        }

        String details1 = serial +doubleTab+ mac;
        String details2 = daaid +doubleTab+ bill;

        textViewlabel.setText(label);
        textViewdetails1.setText(details1);
        textViewdetails2.setText(details2);


        return customView;
    }


    public String getAllElements(){
        return allElementsAdapter;
    }

    public void setCheckBoxSelectItemVisible(){
        checkBoxSelectItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return;
    }

    public void setCheckBoxSelectItemGone(){
        checkBoxSelectItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you can access it from fragment or can create listener to CustomAdapter

Comment: How is the syntax? If I want to access to MainActivity's method I use `((MainActivity) getActivity()).methodname();` But whats the Fragments equivalent? Something like `((CustomAdapter) getApplicationContext) methodname();`?

Comment: no not method you have to create Interface and pass it to CustomAdapter to callback

Comment: please upload your fragment and Custom Adapter class

Comment: added the CustomAdapter and the (shorted version) of my Fragment

Comment: you have to visible checkBoxSelectItem of Listview after long click on perticular listview row..right..?

Comment: ok give me few I will upload solution..

Comment: Done with code hope work fine....!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with ((BaseAdapter)dataListAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();

Answer (score 0):

first change your Custom Adapter constructor with following

```
    ArrayList<Boolean> mIsVisible;
    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, String[] dataListFinal,ArrayList<Boolean> isVisible) {
            super(context, R.layout.list_item_datalist ,dataListFinal);
            mIsVisible = isVisible;
    }
```

then modify getView()

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater iteminflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = iteminflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_datalist, parent, false);

        ImageView image = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.list_icon_product);
        TextView textViewlabel = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_datalist_label_textview);
        TextView textViewdetails1 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_datalist_textview_details_1);
        TextView textViewdetails2 = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_datalist_textview_details_2);
        checkBoxSelectItem = (CheckBox) customView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_Item);

        String singleListItem = getItem(position);
        String[] singleListItemArray = singleListItem.split("\t");
        String id = singleListItemArray[0];
        String product = singleListItemArray[1];



        allElementsAdapter = product + label + serial + mac + daaid + bill;

        switch (product) {
            case "Pc":
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_pc_circle);
                break;
            case "Laptop":
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_laptop_circle);
                break;
        }

        String details1 = serial +doubleTab+ mac;
        String details2 = daaid +doubleTab+ bill;

        textViewlabel.setText(label);
        textViewdetails1.setText(details1);
        textViewdetails2.setText(details2);

        if(mIsVisible.get(position)){
            checkBoxSelectItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            checkBoxSelectItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        return customView;
    }
```

After that modify your activity CustomAdapter creation part

```
    final ArrayList<Boolean> isVisible=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    for(int count =0 ;count<dataListArray.length; count++){
        isVisible.add(false);
    }
    final ListAdapter dataListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, dataListArray, isVisible);
```

And last modify listener part

```
    dataListListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(isVisible.get(position)) 
                    isVisible.set(position,false);
                else
                    isVisible.set(position,true);
                dataListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
    });
```

Done...!!!!!

Comment: And I think this is not exactly what I need. On Longclick EVERY checkbox in my list should be checkable. But first, thank you for your help ;)

EDIT: It works with `((BaseAdapter)dataListAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();`